# Do I need to worry about memory leaks in Mac app development?

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am working on an application for the Mac App Store. Unlike iOS, Mac applications leverage Garbage Collection.

My question is, do I need to worry about memory leaks in Mac app development or is it good practice to clean it yourself like you do in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unlike iOS, Mac applications leverage Garbage Collection.

Did you turn on the garbage collection in the compiler setting?  Note that it is an opt-in technology.
If you don't, you have to do retain/release.

If you do turn on the garbage collection, memory management is automatically done for you, as long as you only use Cocoa objects. Core Foundation objects are not automatically taken care of, so you need some care if you use `CF...` methods.

For more on garbage collection, read [the official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/GarbageCollection/Introduction.html).

Comment: That's great. Yes I have garbage collection enabled. Thanks for the answer.